# sharing SQL database between two or more android clients

Tags: android, sql, servlets

I have created a java servlet with which I have attached SQL database. Android client is sendig data to java servlet to save it in database which is working fine. I want to know if multiple android clients will share the same database connection or do i need to do some threading or something else?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion You should synchronize databases on Android devices with servlet. Synchronization is not easy to make. I don't found ready class or library for it.

Maybe you find something on stackoverflow ;-)